# Understanding app_exception event more in frirebase analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics-firebase

I've looked at all similar questions related to the topic, but still, it's not clear for me.

Does app_exception mean that the app actually crashed and the application was actually closed?

Or

Does it mean that there was an error in some function or code inside the app, that was caught and handled and didn't cause the application to close, but still analytics reported that it was an exception?

In other words, I went to Bigquery and expanded the event parameters for app_exception, and checked the 'fatal' parameters, and it was all 1. does that mean that all the crashes caused the app to close?

Answer (score 0):

"app_exception: when the app crashes or throws an exception fatal. Parameters: timestamp, engagement_time_msec"

Reference: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en.